# Jquery contains selects div too high up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is a complete bonehead move on my side, but can't figure out what's happening here.

I'm trying to select a div with a specific word in it, but Jquery seems to select the div on the wrong level. If you run this you'll see what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".ms-my-profileDetails:contains('Birthday')").css("color", "red");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ms-my-profileDetails">
        <div>
            Department : <a href='http://Someurl'>IT</a>
        </div>        
        <br />
        <div>
            Birthday : <a href='http://Someurl'>1921-04-13</a>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of the above contains matches the entire div of Birthday and Department    `<div class="ms-my-profileDetails">` when I only want the Birthday Div.

Pls help.
Tx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should to something like:

```
$(".ms-my-profileDetails").children(":contains('Birthday')").css("color", "red");
```

That should look only on child divs and therefore select the div you want in this case...

Comment: Hey, np I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around why my initial code didn't work.... Why does it select the parent? Strange one

Comment: That's because the `:contains()` works on the current selector you have, (in this case the parent) and the parent "contains" Birthday (in one of the children but still)

Comment: Ok, makes sense.. darkajax, your answer was the first correct.. i'll make it correct in 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Antons solution, no idea if it is more efficient

```
$(".ms-my-profileDetails > div:contains('Birthday')").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:last` using contains gets all elements with the keyword you are searching for, so you must use :last to get the exact element that contains it

```
$("div:contains('Birthday'):last").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because my div's are dynamic.. ASP.Net might put something before or after my 'birthday' div

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong.
You tell jQuery to search the element with ".ms-my-profileDetails" that contains "Birthday".
There's only 1 element in your html with that.

Now, you want the div containing "Birthday" INSIDE the element with ".ms-my-profileDetails". That would be :

```
$(".ms-my-profileDetails div:contains('Birthday')").css("color", "red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pquT7/

Answer (score 0):

tyr this

```
$(".ms-my-profileDetails").children().last().css("color", "red");
```